# Prove that $\lim_{x ->2}\frac{x^3 - 4}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{4}{5}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to prove this statement using the definition of limit, but the expression $|\frac{x^3 - 4}{x^2 + 1} - \frac{4}{5}|$ looks terrible for me. I tried to simplify this term and got $|x-2||1 + \frac{6x + 7}{5x^2 + 5}|$. How can I proceed to prove this?

Comment: "... the expression... looks terrible" is one of the reasons for not showing such limit by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. Instead, one would use "properties" of limits.

Comment: One tip for MathJax: Instead of `x->2`, one uses `x\to 2` for $x\to 2$.

Comment: Do you mean I should use is both f(x) and g(x) are convergent then $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ = $\lim(f(x))$$\lim(g(x))$

Comment: @TobyMak What are you talking about? Of course you want a factor of $|x-2|$.

Comment: Alternatively you could just substitute $x=2$ since you don't have an indeterminate form. Is this what you want?

Comment: The OP is trying to do a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof with the definition of limit. That's what the question states.

Comment: An instructor in calculus seldom gives such exercise (using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to show some limits that would be calculated in practice using just properties of limits), *unless*, of course, students are particularly instructed to do such exercise on purpose: to see how some proof of a general statement works in some concrete cases. On the other hand, some students may not notice that one does not need to reinvent the wheel, and being rigorous is by no means only using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"... the expression... looks terrible" is one of the reasons for not showing such limit by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. Instead, one would use "properties" of limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)}
$$
when both $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)$ exist and $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)\neq 0$.

If you do want to proceed in that way, 
$$
|5(x^3-4)-4(x^2+1)|=|5(x^3-4)-5\cdot 4+5\cdot 4-4(x^2+1)|
<5|x^3-8|+4\cdot |4-x^2|
$$
Now, note that
$$
x^3-9=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4),\quad x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You've started just fine. Suppose now that $|x-2|<1$, say, so $1<x<3$.  What is the largest that $\left|1+\dfrac{6x+7}{5(x^2+1)}\right|$ will be on that interval? Can you finish now?

Answer (score 1):

It actually simplifies  as $$|\frac{x^3 - 4}{x^2 + 1} - \frac{4}{5}|=|x-2||1+ \frac{6x + 7}{5x^2 + 5}|$$

Since you may assume $\delta <1$ you may assume $1<x<3$ so you have a bound on $$|1+ \frac{6x + 7}{5x^2 + 5}|$$

For example you have $$|1+ \frac{6x + 7}{5x^2 + 5}|<\frac {35}{10}$$

Thus  if $\delta <1$ then

$$|\frac{x^3 - 4}{x^2 + 1} - \frac{4}{5}|=|x-2|| \frac{6x + 7}{5x^2 + 5}|< (7/2)|x-2| <\epsilon$$

If $$|x-2|<(2/7)\epsilon$$

Therefore $$\delta = \min \{1, \frac {2\epsilon}{7}\}$$ works.